# Separating mixed data types from a single character vector

Tags: r

I read data from a database into a data frame.  One of the columns that was typed character in the database is now chr in R but it contains a mixture of numeric values, various codes as character strings and spaces.

```
data <- c("0.1", "0.2", "NNN", "RBGT", "", "", "")
```

I would like to subset that vector to get just the rows with values that would successfully convert to numeric.  The vector is over 2 million rows and the number of codes is in the '000's.

Comment: Just run `as.numeric` on it.  Values that can not be converted will become NA.  So you could do `data[!is.na(as.numeric(data))]`

Comment: Wow, how red is my face.  I'm getting too enamored with things like dplyr.